# Load custom block content inside class

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module, class

I have a module in which a protected variable is defined as follows:

```
protected $stores = array('a','b', 'c', 'd');
```

I want to load define this variable inside a custom block so I am trying to do this:

```
protected $staticBlock = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('custom_block')->getContent();

protected $stores = array($staticBlock);
```

This gives me PHP errors of course.

It really sounds like a newling question, but the real problem is that I tried to transform it into a function, but the entire code uses the variable without calling anything except the variable directly. I am really lost now and can't find a way to achieve this.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood what you want... why not just this?

```
protected $staticBlock = null;
```

And then, before using **$this->staticBlock** property (in class constructor, for instance, if that fits your needings)

```
$this->staticBlock = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('custom_block')->getContent();
```

About **$this->stores** property, I am not totally sure what you are asking for, or if that's just an example

**UPDATE**

If you want to avoid calling multiple times that code you can use a helper class, which is always instantiated as singleton https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/74991/3566, something like this

```
protected $staticBlock = null;

public function getStaticBlock()
{
    if (is_null($this->staticBlock)){
        $this->staticBlock = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('custom_block')->getContent();
    }
    return $this->staticBlock;
}
```

Comment: What I was trying is to define the variable without having to redeclare it every time the module calls $this->staticBlock. But yes, I think I will have to do it this way. Thank you!

Comment: Nice, feel free to accept the answer as valid if it helped

Comment: I have completed a bit my answer